# How to not dismiss the keyboard on return key in ios

Tags: ios, keyboard, return

Everything I read about this topic is wanting to dismiss the keyboard. This seems weird because that seems to be the default behavior for my app is to dismiss the keyboard when I really want a carriage return in the field.

I have a UITextView as a notes field in my contact page. I have it set to default Return Key and the Auto-enable return key is checked. I tried unchecking that without any change.

When I am in my app and hit the return key the keyboard just goes away. I want the keyboard to stay and a new line to appear in the text.

I am building with xcode 5.1 targeting ios 7.

Comment: Post relevant code for your `UITextViewDelegate` methods. You must be calling `resignFirstResponder` somewhere (or `endEditing:`). The keyboard does not automatically dismiss pressing return unless you have code that causes it to.

Comment: BTW - you need to move to iOS 8 and Xcode 6. Your app can still support iOS 7 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following line :

```
[textView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
```

and check code for following deleget method :

```
 - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range  replacementText:(NSString *)text
    {

        // remove below line of code If your are using
        //if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) 
        //{
          //  [txtView resignFirstResponder];
           // return NO;
        // }
       return YES;
    }
```

Comment: I feel very stupid. Someone else wrote a lot of this code. They had the resignFirstResponder in the base class for this view. I should have just searched for that code in the project. I knew it had to be there, but didn't see it in my view class. My view class does not have any of the delegates in it, so I missed it. Thank you all for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I used textView and default behaviour for me is it's adding new line.

Comment: Read question, user want to resign keyboard for UITextView not for UITextField.

Comment: Its hide keyboard , use dont want to hide keyboard when press retun key.

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya I used textView and set it to default Return Key and the Auto-enable return key is checked. Still keyboard is not dismissed and as for default behaviour it's just creating new line.

Comment: Yes,you are right.But here in this case @user856232 set code for resign keyboard when return key press. Because of this reason keyboard is dismiss in above case of Question asked.

Comment: okay fine but I don't really saw any sign of that code part. Still u did great :) and once again thanks for correcting me.